# I am having trouble organising boxes in css

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and I am trying to create a big square that contains two rows of two smaller squares per row numbered 1 through 4. Currently I have this html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container6">
        <div class="group">
            <div class="item">1</div>
            <div class="item">2</div>
        </div>
       

        <div class="group">
            <div class="item">3</div>
            <div class="item">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

with this css code:

```
.container6{
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;

    margin: 10px;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;

    gap: 10px;
    
}

.container6 .group{
   width: 50px;
   min-height: 50px;
   margin: 10px;

   gap: 10px;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   align-content: center;

}

.container6 .group .item{
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;

}
```

with the result I show in the image.

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkMty.png)

My question is: why aren't boxes 1 and 2 in the same line and how can I flip box 2 with box 3 without obviously modifying the html.

Thank you!

Comment: _"why aren't boxes 1 and 2 in the same line"_ - because you used `flex-direction: row;` on the container, and that means its children - which are your `.group` elements - are laid out _next_ to each other, as _columns_.

Comment: _"how can I flip box 2 with box 3 without obviously modifying the html"_ - since they have different parents, I don't think there is an easy way to do this. If they all had the same parent, then you could use the `order` property. (But I am guessing, once you fixed your first problem, you would not actually need to "flip" them any more?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified your code below to meet your desired output. Try to run it.

Brief explanation.

I made your container6 `flex-flow` into `column` so that it will stack the 1 and 2 above 3 and 4.

Next, I removed the wrap of your group flex-flow so it can arrange your boxes into row. Then added the 50% width to your items and 60% width to your group instead of 50px;

```css
.container6{
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;

    margin: 10px;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;

    gap: 10px;
    
}

.container6 .group{
   width: 60%;
   min-height: 50px;
   margin: 10px;

   gap: 10px;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-content: center;

}

.container6 .group .item{
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;

}
```

```html
 <div class="container6">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
    </div>


    <div class="group">
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```